# Получить значение из listbox, заполненного после postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

На странице есть `DropDownList`, `ListBox` и `Button`.
При выборе элемента в `DropDownList` происходит `postback` и меняется содержание `ListBox`.

```
//SQL запрос
SqlDataReader sqlreader = ExecuteReader();
ListBox1.DataSource = sqlreader;
ListBox1.DataValueField = "value";
ListBox1.DataTextField = "text";
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку `ListBox1.SelectedValue` не возвращает никакого значения.

Если сделать так:

```
//SQL запрос
SqlDataReader sqlreader = ExecuteReader();
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ListBox1.DataSource = sqlreader;
    ListBox1.DataValueField = "value";
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "text";
    ListBox1.DataBind();
}
```

Тогда `ListBox1.SelectedValue` возвращает значение, но тогда при выборе другого пункта `DropDownList1` содержание `ListBox1` не меняется. Потому что уже был обратный вызов.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы после выбора в `DropDown` менялось содержание `ListBox`, и выбранное там значение можно было бы получить после нажатия на кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `DropDownList1` проставьте `AutoPostBack=True`.

Вынесите код заполнения ListBox в отдельный метод.

```
private void BindListBox()
{
    using (SqlDataReader sqlreader = ExecuteReader())
    {
        ListBox1.DataSource = sqlreader;
        ListBox1.DataValueField = "value";
        ListBox1.DataTextField = "text";
        ListBox1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Вызывайте этот метод в двух местах:

1. В `OnPreRender` страницы, с проверкой на `!IsPostBack` - для первоначального заполнения списка:

   ```
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       ListBox1.DataBind();
   }
   ```
2. В обработчике `SelectedIndexChanged` для `DropDownList1` - без проверки `IsPostBack` - для смены содержимого списка при выборе нового значения:

   ```
   ListBox1.DataBind();
   ```

Comment: В моем коде заполнение `ListBox` уже было вынесено в отдельный метод, но ошибка значит была в том, что я вызывал один и тот-же метод в `Page_Load` и `SelectedIndexChanged`.
Помог ваш ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: @PavelJer кстати, в web forms принято заполнять данными контролы не в Page_Load, а в PreRender - как можно позже. от загрузки страницы до PreRender может много чего произойти - например, пользователя перенаправит на другую страницу. Поэтому обычно весь код датабайнда ставят попозже. Стандартные DataBoundControls кстати тоже срабатывают именно в OnPreRender